# Registration form django that inherits form UserCreationForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I am following a tutorial that has created the following registration form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

        def save(self, commit = True):
            user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit= False)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

            if commit:
                user.save()

                return User
```

Why is`email = forms.EmailField(required = True)` the only field mentioned outside of `class Meta`, what is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 0):

`email` field on the [`contrib.auth.AbstractUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser) (which is subclassed by `User`) has:

```
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
```

which means that it is allowed to be [blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#blank).

Because we want it to be required in the form (for the purposes of the tutorial I assume), we must declare it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create user registration system in django you can create forms.py file paste within it :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Repeat password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}),
            'email':    forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'input'})
        }

    # Validating password
    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password2'] != cd['password']:
            raise ValidationError("Password don't match")

        return cd['password2']
```

And in views.py

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from account.forms import RegisterUserForm


class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    template_name = "account/register.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        return super(RegisterUserView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return HttpResponse('User registered')
```

We override the **dispath()** method to make sure that the user can access the form if and only if he's not authenticated .
And for form_valid method we encrypt the password using **set_password()** method and then we commit to the database.
You probably will redirect the user if success rather than returning **HttpResponse()** as i did .

Answer (score 0):

Because the default `UserCreationForm` doesn't have the `EmailField` which represents the email. But it has the other fields and there's no need to add them.

If you added a special field that is not included in the `UserCreationForm` like the `EmailField` you have to add it there.